# Solved React, pass object as params to page, not display in html, but will in console

Tags: reactjs

I just pass in object from one page to another. I then take the object and loop through it to display it in html. It will not display anything in html but will console.log it.
Here is the code. query.tags is an array.
I tried using state just for testing and it didnt change anything.

```
const {query} = useRouter();
    
    console.log(query.id, query.title, query.description, query.segment);
    const [stateTags, setStateTags] = useState(query.tags);
    const tags = () => {
        console.log(stateTags);
        console.log("new here--", query.tags);
        query.tags?.map((tag, index) => {
            console.log(tag)
            return (
                <Tag key={index}>{tag}</Tag>
            );
        }); 
    };
    return (
      <div>{query.tags?.map((tag, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Tag key={index}>{tag}</Tag>
                    );
                })}</div>
    );
```

Can someone explain to me why it will display in console, but not in the dom/html.
SOLVED

Comment: Where is this code in the component as a whole? The tags() function is returning a value, but is it in the render output of the component?

Comment: You need to call the ````tags()```` function in order for it to render.  Right now, you have a function that is not being called.  You'll need to call it return block to render somewhere but with your current code snippet, we don't know enough about your existing code to give advice.

Comment: sorry I do call the tags function in the html, ill update

Comment: yes I call the function in the html

Comment: Your `tags` function does not return anything. It just calls `map()` on `query.tags` but doesn't use the result. It should probably be `return query.tags?.map(...)`.

Comment: Ok you are right, I had it before so the map was in the html and it wasnt working so I thought put it in a function and see whats going on, so I took the map brought it into html and it works now. Dumb me

Comment: @noobCoder It's jsx, not html.

Answer (score 1):

Your tags function is not returning anything. Try to return add before map function.

Try:-

```
return query.tags?.map((tag, index) => (
  <Tag key={index}>{tag}</Tag>
));
```

Comment: I realised what I did, but ill give you credit because its basically what i did